# Python scikit-image pull request Travis CI Python 2.7 build fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, scikit-image, scikits

I'm trying to submit [pull request](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1769), but Travis [build](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/jobs/92664060) fails under python 2.7:

> Install optional dependencies
>   +[[ 2.7 != 3.2* ]]
>   +pip install --retries 3 -q -r ./optional_requirements.txt --no-index --  trusted-host travis-wheels.scikit-image.org --find-links=http://travis-wheels.scikit-image.org/
>   +[[ 2.7 == 2.7* ]]
>   +LIBS=(PyQt4 sip.so)
>   +VAR=($(which -a python$PY))
>   ++which -a python2.7
>   +GET_PYTHON_LIB_CMD='from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print (get_python_lib())'
>   ++python -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print (get_python_lib())'
>   +LIB_VIRTUALENV_PATH=/home/travis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   ++/usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print (get_python_lib())'
>   +LIB_SYSTEM_PATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   +for LIB in '${LIBS[@]}'
>   +ln -sf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4 /home/travis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4
>   +for LIB in '${LIBS[@]}'
>   +ln -sf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so /home/travis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
>   +[[ 2.7 == 2.* ]]
>   +pip install --retries 3 -q pyamg
>   Command "/home/travis/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-RPE1oa/pyamg/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(`__file__`).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), `__file__`,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VfR9HT-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/travis/venv/include/site/python2.7/pyamg" failed with error code
>   1 in /tmp/pip-build-RPE1oa/pyamg

I've tried almost everything, but still can't pass the tests.

I would appreciate any help with the code or understanding why the build fails, because I have no clue, why is it happening. I even tried replacing newline characters, but it didn't help

Comment: Is that all the traceback?

Comment: Yeah. It is available [here](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/jobs/92664060)
UPD: Included log in the initial post.

Comment: Did you try install `pyamg` yourself?

Comment: Yeah. I have no problems with 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the issue with your pull-request, it is a general issue with this project and `pyamg`. See the [latest builds](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/builds): they all fail with the same issue.

The first [failing build](https://travis-ci.org/scikit-image/scikit-image/jobs/91338994) with this error was **19 days ago**. As you can see the `install` script does not specify the version of the `pyamg`:

```
pip install --retries 3 -q pyamg
```

And `pyamg` package's version [was bumped](https://github.com/pyamg/pyamg/tags) from 2.2.x to 2.3.x **26 days ago** and from 2.x to 3.x **14 day ago**.

Comment: Thank you!

Repository owner opened the [issue](https://github.com/pyamg/pyamg/issues/163) at pyamg repository, I hope they will fix problem.